# MVC3 - Display literal that parses as XML

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This question feels ridiculous...I wrote literal text in Index.cshtml:

`<div> blah blah blah <HereBeSomeText>.  Blahdy friggen blah.</div>`

How do I escape or write out `<HereBeSomeText>` so that it is displayed as content on the page rather than interpreted as bad HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the common entities for `<` and `>`:

```
<div> blah blah blah &lt;HereBeSomeText&gt;. Blahdy friggen blah.</div>
```

Comment: Sometimes the solution is just too simple, no? ;)

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not a Razor expert, it seems like something like this ought to work:

```
<div>
    @"blah blah blah <HereBeSomeText>. Blahdy friggen blah."
</div>
```

or

```
<div>
    @new HtmlString(
        Html.Encode("blah blah blah <HereBeSomeText>. Blahdy friggen blah."))
</div>
```

The actual HTML produced would be something like:

```
<div>
    blah blah blah &lt;HereBeSomeText&gt;. Blahdy friggen blah.
</div>
```

... in which the browser would convert < and > to `<` and `>` respectively.

Comment: I tried this before I posted.  It doesn't work `&lt;HereBeSomeText&gt;.` gets printed out instead.  Also tried `@Response.Write()` which fails as well.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: Okay, that makes sense: Razor is double-encoding the string. Try my updated sample.